# What are the differences between lgroupadd and groupadd?

Tags: linux, group

`lgroupadd` is provided by `libuser`.
`groupadd` is provided by `shadow`.

Both create user groups.

I couldn't find the difference between the two on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `man lgroupadd` and `man groupadd`:

- `lgroupadd` only has a small number of configuration options, to choose the new group’s group identifier (either explicitly, or choosing between user groups and system groups).
- `groupadd` has many options; the main additions over `lgroupadd` are the ability to set a group password, and the ability to modify files in a directory other than `/etc`.

`lgroupadd` does support some of `groupadd`’s additional features, but not through its command-line options: they require modification of its configuration file, `libuser.conf`.

There are technical differences too: `lgroupadd` requires `libuser` and a few other libraries, and thus ends up being “heavier” to install than `groupadd`. Another consideration is that `groupadd` is available by default in most non-cloud setups of Linux distributions, `lgroupadd` isn’t.